# Change value of opener document by jquery with data from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a problem with change value of opener document by jquery with data from mysql. Mysql data is displayed in table, in every TR I have button which should change data in opener document with data from mysql but it puts everywhere 0. Where is the problem? I have a following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".formbutton").click(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parents('tr');
            var nazwa = $('#nazwa', parent).val();
            var osoba = $('#osoba', parent).val();
            var nip = $('#nip', parent).val();
            $("#nazwa",opener.document).val(+nazwa)
            $("#adres",opener.document).val(+osoba)
            $("#nip",opener.document).val(+nip)
            window.opener.focus();
            window.close();
        });
</script>

<? echo'<table>                
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nazwa</th>
                        <th>Osoba</th>
                        <th>Nip</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr></thead><tbody>';
    $id=$_GET['id'];      
    $link=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM qwerty where qwerty like '%$id%'");
    while($wiersz=mysql_fetch_array($link))
    {
    echo'<tr>';
    echo'<td id="nazwa">'.$wiersz['nazwa'].'</td>';
    echo'<td id="osoba">'.$wiersz['osoba'].'</td>';
    echo'<td id="nip">'.$wiersz['nip'].'</td>';
    ?>
    <td align="center" width="260px"><form><input type="button" class="formbutton" value="PUT IN"/></form></td>

    <?
    }
    echo'</tbody></table></div>';   ?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a fast note: You should *not* use same IDs for the fields for each row. This is a basic HTML rule, id *must* be unique in the HTML document. You should number your id's like nazwa1 nazwa2 nazwa3 for each row and nazwadisplay for the popup for instance

Comment: Following the basic programmation rules will surely remove you a huge headache when you need to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.val()` on a `td` doesn't work.
Use e.g. `var nazwa = $('#nazwa', parent).text();` or `var nazwa = $('#nazwa', parent).html();`

Finally, as mentioned by PH. T. ids must be unique, so use css classes:

```
var nazwa= $('.nazwa', parent).text();
...

 $("#nazwa",opener.document).val(+nazwa)
...


echo'<td class="nazwa">'.$wiersz['nazwa'].'</td>';
```

I assume that the td named nazwa contains a number and that #nazwa in parent is a unique form element.

Comment: Thanks for help. I found one more bug - It should be  $("#nazwa",opener.document).val(nazwa) no  $("#nazwa",opener.document).val(+nazwa)